# Make Implicit Dependancy

Tags: makefile

In a Makefile, is there any way of making a rule an implicit dependency of all other rules?

Say, for instance, i wanted a rule run whenever the Makefile is run, regardless of which rule is actually being requested. How would i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why you'd want to do this, but in GNU make you can do this by `-include`-ing a `.PHONY` file:

```
.PHONY: run-always
-include run-always
run-always:
    echo "trololol"
```

Comment: +1. I hate Jack Kelly with every fiber of my being, but this is ingenious.

Comment: Brilliant...thanks! The only reason i want to do this is to print some instructional text whenever the makefile is run.

Comment: @Beta: The feeling's mutual, in that friendly-rivalry sort of way.

Comment: Friendly riv... that's the kind of nemesis you think I am? Oh, it's on. I'm going to go kill one of my henchmen, maybe take a little "me time", then it's *on*.

Comment: @Beta: So be it! Have at you, _sir!_

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't want to do something, but bravo for having the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Include a wildcard rule:

```
%: mydependency
```

I've tried this, the following makefile is a proof of concept

```
all: a b

a:
    touch $@

%: ccc
    #

ccc::
    touch ccc
```

Note the use of

1. [Double-Colon Rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon)
2. [Match-Anything Pattern Rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules)

In order to prevent the dependency from building unconditionally each time, you might want to make it an indirect dependency (requirement for the `ccc::` rule above, instead of directly on the wildcard rule).

Good luck

Comment: not exactly what i wanted. I'm thinking whether i run "make a" "make b" or "make", 'echo implicit dependency' will run.
`
all: a b

a:
 touch $@

b: 
 touch $@

%: 
 echo implicit dependancy
`

edit: can't seem to get the `code` mini-markdown to work.

Comment: @Woodrow: right I cannot parse that comment. Feel free to update your question and leave me a note